# visual basic 12 windows form

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-forms-designer

I am new to using windows form C# in visual basic 12 . In a ASP.NET form, you can right click on a linkbutton or imagelink, click preferences, and enter in a form under postbackurl to go to the that form after clicking the link/image. How is this done using a linklabel in a windows form? I cannot seem to figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code you're looking for (by example).

Of course form2 is a new separate form. ;)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 newForm = new Form2();
        newForm.Show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to do that?

Windows Forms work on a very different way and level opposed to Web based forms.

In web based forms you have a kind of navigation where you go from one to another page. The original page kind of seizes to exist.

In windows forms you will always have a master window (your application) which call's other windows to open.

The closest thing you can achieve is a linkbutton that opens a new Window or you have to use webpages inside the browsercontrol inside your Windows Form window.

Comment: Yes that is my question. Like i said, i have never used windows form before.. If i have a main form acting as a main menu, how do i access another form from that form? I was curious if it was along the lines of going into preferences of a button or link label and doing it there.